# Nodemailer stops sending mails after a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer to send mails if "/send" is called with an email (receiver) and token variable. It works perfectly however it stops responding after a few hours... It has worked for days before without problems but recently it can't even last a few hours.

No error codes are displayed, cmd only shows the output of the last sent email. It still runs, but doesn't respond to "/send" calls anymore. Is this a known issue? What can I do to figure out what's wrong?

Below is my app.js. It's nothing special, mostly standard nodemailer code.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

const https = require('https') // to run https
var fs = require('fs') // to run https

// View engine setup
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: false }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cors());

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.data.email;
    const token = req.body.data.token;
    const output = fs.readFileSync('employee.html').toString().replace("${token}", token);

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    name: "myname",
    host: "myhost",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "info@myhost.nl",
      pass: "123456",
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
    logger: true, // If set to true then logs to console.
    debug: true, // if set to true, then logs SMTP traffic, otherwise logs only transaction events.
  }));

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"MyName" <info@myhost.nl>', 
    to: email,
    subject: "account", 
    html: output, 
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object to employee
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    res.render("contact", { msg: "Email has been sent" });
    console.log("Email has been sent");
  });
});

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('../cert/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../cert/certificate.crt')
}, app)
.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3001! Go to https://localhost:3001/')
})
```

Comment: you dont have a `res.send()` etc to resolve so it will just keep hanging

Comment: @LawrenceCherone My bad I removed it for testing but it is in there. (edited)

Comment: you need to respond even if there is an mailing error or not `return console.log(error);` would prevent it going to the next line.. switch from console.log to something which logs to file, [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) etc, then your see the errors, if your using pm2 use console.error instead then it will be in pm2 logs